# Using TimedRotatingFileHandler logging with a logging.config

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to test using a TimedRotatingFileHandler with a logging.config file, nothing that complicated but it should roll over every 10 seconds into a new log file.

However I'm getting the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testLogging.py", line 6, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig(logDir+'logging.conf')
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
    handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\config.py", line 159, in _install_handlers
    h = klass(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\logging\handlers.py", line 195, in __init__
    raise ValueError("You must specify a day for weekly rollover from 0 to 6 (0
is Monday): %s" % self.when)
ValueError: You must specify a day for weekly rollover from 0 to 6 (0 is Monday)
: WHEN='S'
```

The python is pretty simple it just sets up an infinite loop that continually logs

```
import logging
import logging.config

logDir = "./logs/"

logging.config.fileConfig(logDir+'logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('root')

while 1==1:        
    logger.info('THIS IS AN INFO MESSAGE')
```

And the config file

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=timedRotatingFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=timedRotatingFormatter

[formatter_timedRotatingFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
datefmt=%m-%d %H:%M

[handlers]
keys=timedRotatingFileHandler

[handler_timedRotatingFileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=timedRotatingFormatter
args=('./logs/log.out', 'when=\'S\'', 'interval=10', 'backupCount=5')
```

As you can see when is set to 'S' not 'W' like the error message seems to indicate.

Edit: As per the answer below the correct syntax in the logging config was

```
args=('./logs/log.out', 'S', 10, 5, None, False, False)
```

Comment: If anyone was wondering why those parameters and why, I think they correspond to TimedRotatingFileHandler constructor, which has this signature:

`def __init__(self, filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False, atTime=None)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
args=('./logs/log.out', 'when=\'S\'', 'interval=10', 'backupCount=5')
```

Doesn't look right.  Try this

```
args=('./logs/log.out', when='S', interval=10, backupCount=5)
```

Or possibly this

```
args=('./logs/log.out','S',10,5)
```

Comment: The last form, I think, should work. Remember - whatever is in args will effectively be passed to `eval()`. I'm not sure your first suggestion will work - I would expect it to raise a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Thanks both, I literally just worked this out myself, it was the last form that works correctly